# How to SUM Multiple Column in SQL using new column name in php

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, **val_His**:

```
Val1  Val2  Val3
10     30     5
20     40    20
30     50     8
50      2     6
60     10    20
```

And I want to get the sum of each column across all rows, like:

**Desired output:**

```
Val_name      Total
Val1           170
Val2           132
Val3           59
```

And I tried using:

```
SELECT
SUM(Val1 Val_name) AS Total
SUM(Val2 Val_name) AS Total
SUM(Val3 Val_name) AS Total
FROM val_His
```

but it isn't working

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When posting questions in the future, please format code blocks by clicking the `{ }` icon while the code block highlighted.

Comment: "But it seems not working" is a very vague statement. When you say it's not working, please indicate what is not working about it... I.e. What errors are you getting? And what output are you receiving? (and) What output are you expecting?

Comment: I can't get the output i want like table 2

Comment: this is not working SELECT 'Val1' as Val_Name, sum(val1) as 'Total' FROM table1
UNION
SELECT 'Val2', sum(val2)FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT 'Val3', sum(val3)FROM table1

Comment: I know you can't get your desired output. What output are you actually getting?

Comment: None!
table1 is my original table, I want to sum each column and total it as two columns

Comment: Is Table2 your desired output?

Comment: yes, table 2 is my desire output

Comment: @doudy_05, I edited your question. In the future, please try to make your problem more easily understood by breaking down what you have, what you want, and what you tried. Your question as it was posted wasn't very clear IMO. And, if you are getting no output, then you should say so in your question. If you are getting the wrong output, you should post the incorrect output. Because if it's no output, then there is likely an error in your syntax. Though, I realize you are new on SO, and there are pretty high standards here, but it's for a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

The way you were attempting would give you three columns with the totaled values. In order to get the results in seperate records you will have to use a UNION query:

```
SELECT 'Val1' as Val_Name, sum(val1) as Total FROM val_his
UNION
SELECT 'Val2', sum(val2) FROM val_his
UNION 
SELECT 'Val3', sum(val3) FROM val_his
```

Only the first of the unioned SELECT statements needs to have the field aliases, the rest of the SELECT statement fields will fit according to the ordinal position.

[Here is a sqlfiddle showing this solution.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/27483/2) It matches your desired output.

Comment: What about this is not working? Can you add your desired output to your question. We are grasping at straws here.

Comment: @doudy_05, are you getting any errors with this solution? You may need to change `table1` to `val_His`, and I think there should be a space between `sum(val2)` and `FROM`

Comment: Thanks @jakar. I updated the answer to point to the correct table, and added a space (although I think the sql would parse fine with it).

Comment: I did and still not getting mu desired output. thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are you getting less columns then you expected? Are you getting more or less records than you expected? Are the values you are getting different from your expectations? I have updated the answer with a sqlfiddle showing a table with your example data and the query above with a match to your desired output. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/27483/2

Comment: @JNevill, Lol. I just did the same thing. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/276974/2 You beat me to it though

Comment: i'm getting this error
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Comment: Oracle is whiny. Try using "Union All" instead of "Union" in that query. Perhaps it doesn't like grouping on top of a the `sum` aggregation.

Comment: I used Union All and I'm getting the same error
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Answer (score 0):

If JNevill's answer is not working for you, you can try this:

```
SELECT 'Val1' as Val_Name, Sum(val1) as Total FROM val_his
UNION
SELECT 'Val2', Sum(val2) FROM val_his
UNION 
SELECT 'Val3', Sum(val3) FROM val_his
```

However, if you don't need it to be in separate rows, the following query will get you the same information but be even faster.

```
select 
  sum(val1) as Val1Total,
  sum(val2) as Val2Total,
  sum(val3) as Val3Total
FROM val_his
```

Comment: This query it's taking a long tine to run because of the UNION; is there any other option?

Comment: @doudy_05 See my edit.  I improved the original query as well as giving you a second option

Comment: that was my initial statement but I'm not getting the desired table, but that's fine. I have another issue; I'm trying to join another table(val_his2) to get one column and doing Sum from table(val_his). how to do that ? Thanks that I'm trying to do is (distinct from table val_his2 and sum from table(val_his) )

Comment: 2 -This is my statement select distinct val_his2.EmID sum(val_his.val1) as Val1Total, sum(val_his.val2) as Val2Total, sum(val_his.val3) as Val3Total FROM val_his right join val_his2 on val_his.prod_name = val_his2.prod_name group by EmID

Comment: get rid of 'distinct' and you need a comma between val_his2.EmID  and sum(val_his.val1) as Val1Total